# Animate.Scroll html,body after page hits offset - Very close (see Fiddle)

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, window, jquery-animate

I'm trying to trigger the window to scroll to a new location after the page has been scrolled down a certain amount. I've got the code working but now I can't scroll back up.

[Here's a fiddle of the code](http://jsfiddle.net/cbart7421/zutw2wz3/)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
var scroll_pos_test = 50;  

if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {

 $('html, body').animate({
 scrollTop: $( ".here" ).offset().top
 }, 500);
}
else{}
});
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to stop the code from working after it runs once. Or even better, only have it work only when the scroll bar is being **scrolled down** over a certain point. Any help or advice would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run it just once

```
var scrolled = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
var scroll_pos_test = 50;             

if(!scrolled && y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
    scrolled = true;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( ".here" ).offset().top
    }, 500);

    $("body").css("background-color","#000");
}

if (y_scroll_pos < scroll_pos_test) {
    scrolled = false;
    $("body").css("background-color","#FFF");
}
});
```

If you want to have it work only when the scroll bar is being scrolled down over a certain point you can get current scroll position with `window.scrollY` and compare it with `offset().top` of your element and then set flag to false or unbind event with `.off('scroll')`.

Comment: Do you know of a way to re-engage the code once the window.pageYoffet is scrolled less than 50?

Comment: If you want to re-active your code when user scrolls back to top of the page you can set `scrolled = false;` in `else`

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well. But it seems when I do that, the code doesn't let me scroll back up. 

http://jsfiddle.net/cbart7421/23g8twxf/

Comment: Replace `else` with this `if (y_scroll_pos < scroll_pos_test)`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to unbind the scroll event handler off the window once you've scrolled once, using .off("scroll"):

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
  var scroll_pos_test = 50;
  // set to whatever you want it to be

  if (y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".here").offset().top
    }, 500);


    $("body").css("background-color", "#000");
    $(window).off("scroll");
  } else {
    $("body").css("background-color", "#FFF");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}
.here {
  position: absoulte;
  margin-top: 1500px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="here"></div>
```